# HTML displaying two div's on the same line

Tags: html, css

Just wondering if anyone can help me to get 1st half and 2nd half on this codepen to display on the same line? I have tried `display:inline;` however this did not fix the issue.

http://codepen.io/EuanR/pen/BNEBvE

HTML:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <title>Homepage</title>
</HEAD>

<HEADER>
  <H1 id="landingpagelg">Header</H1>
  <H2 id="landingpagesm">Sub Header</H2>
</HEADER>

<BODY>
  <div class="footerwrapper">
    <div class="BFS">
      <P>1st half</P>
    </div>
    <div class="BLFS">
      <P>2nd half</P>
    </div>
  </div>
  </script>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #161616;
}

header {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/11nVLmd.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center
}

#landingpagelg {
  font-family: Caviar Dreams;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #FFF;
  letter-spacing: 1px
}

#landingpagesm {
  font-family: Caviar Dreams;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #FFF
}

#CMSub {
  min-width: 75px;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

a.hover {
  color: 0000EE;
}

::selection {
  background: #FFB870;
  /*#CCCCCC*/
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #FFB870;
}

img::selection {
  background: transparent
}

img::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent
}

input {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 4px;
}

textarea {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 125px;
}

#github {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.footerwrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.BFS {
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #161616;
}

.BLFS {
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    .footerwrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
}
```

Display Flex solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit your CSS, then simply add the following lines

```
.footerwrapper {
    font-size: 0; /*Removes white space in inline-block elements*/
}

.BFS {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}

.BLFS {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Make sure you set the `font-size` in every element that is a child of `.footerwrapper`

Comment: "If you don't want to edit your CSS, just add these lines of CSS"

Answer (score 0):

```
.footerwrapper {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.BFS {
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #161616;
    width: 50%;
    float:left; /* add this */
}

.BLFS {
    height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  float:left; /* add this */
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.BFS {float:left;}
.BLFS {float:right;}
```

Alternatively put the BLFS element first in your HTML and float it to the right. Then the `.BFS{float:left;}` is unnecessary since it will fill on the left anyway.